# When is it necessary to use fixed viewport's width?

Tags: html, css

I've noticed that https://graphql.github.io/ uses fixed viewport's width

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640">
```

instead of recommended way for creating responsive websites

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1>
```

But it still looks good on mobiles.

So, can anybody explain what is the purpose of using fixed width viewport and when is is appropriate?

Comment: Give this a read - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#Viewport_width_and_screen_width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devices with less than 640px width will zoom out the content (if you set initial-scale=1 then devices won't zoom it out and you have horizontal scroll).

It looks good on mobile but it looks small and you have to zoom in to read some texts.

The advantage is that you don't need to design your site for resolutions below 640px, but the tradeoff is that users have to zoom in.